# Is "to be innocent" in the accused declared himself to be innocent the object complement?

Tags: complements

> The accused declared himself to be innocent.

Got a quick question, is **to be innocent** the object complement?

Comment: why was there a person clicked and downvoted the question and didn't even drop an answer, omg I hate it, I hope the one who did it was not a native speaker

Comment: As a native speaker I had to look up what an 'object complement' was (!), but, yes, it appears to be one.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Your reply had me laughing so hard hh, thanks for that.

Comment: No: object complements are either NPs or AdjPs, but not clauses. Your example has "himself" as object and the infinitival clause "to be innocent" as complement of "declared". "Himself" is of course the predicand for the AdjP "innocent".

Answer (score 0):

> *The accused declared himself* [*to be innocent*].

No: object complements are either NPs or AdjPs, but not clauses.

Your example has "himself" as object and the subordinate infinitival clause "to be innocent" as complement of "declared". "Himself" is the predicand for the depictive AdjP "innocent".

Note that "himself" is the syntactic object of "declared" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause. It's called a 'raised' object because the verb that "himself" relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.